# TFS Visual studio 2k13

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Suppose I have a team project in tfs and every time I check in, a new build takes place. Now what I want is that suppose I add a class library to the solution then when I build it a new dll is formed for the class library. So when I check in I want the tfs to just copy only what wasn't there before in the server, i.e.. the class library dll not the whole project again.
Is this possible and how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add the class library to the version control, it will not be checked in. If it is added by default, you can exclude it when you check in. (in other words, you can always select and add to the source control workspace)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a TFS 2013 server with a continuous integration build?  And you want to set the CI build to be an incremental build?

Assuming you are using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml build template, then in your build definition you should check out:

**Clean Workspace** [true/false] which controls whether the build agent pulls down all the code again or only things that have changed.

**Clean Build** [true/false] which controls if everything is built again or only things that are new (like your class library).  This setting only takes effect if Clean Workspace is set to false.

[More details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547(v=vs.120).aspx)